# Nonce of an account or contract in etherscan

Tags: etherscan, nonce

According to ethereum.org, nonce is a counter that indicates the number of transactions sent from the account, and in a contract account, this number represents the number of contracts created by the account.
I want to check the nonce on different accounts, but I can't find it in etherscan. Is there any service that shows me the nonce?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Etherscan shows you the nonce of accounts.
First please check all of the confirmed transactions on address.
Please click this Number. If there's no number, that means that address didn't make any transaction.

[image]

There, Please find out the first out going transaction.
And please click that transaction.

[image]

There please click "Click to see More".
[image]

Noe you can see the latest nonce of this address.

[image]

Comment: What about the nonce of a contract?

Comment: Sorry MohammadHosein. I tried to find the way to get nonce of smart contract on etherscan but failed.
For exmple, https://etherscan.io/address/0x5c69bee701ef814a2b6a3edd4b1652cb9cc5aa6f
creates several smart contracts but I can not check any nonce increase there...

But there's a way to get the nonce of the smart contract.
The nonce can be obtained by using web3.eth.getTransactionCount.
So please use this method.